# Interior of a set in a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

if $E$ is a metric space nd $B\neq E$ how to prove that:

$$\overset{\circ}{B}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (\{x\in E,  d(x, E\setminus B)\geq \frac1n\})$$ 
i don't know how to start

Comment: what is $C_EB$ ?

Comment: @Svetoslav : probably $E \setminus B$.

Comment: @Svetoslav $E\setminus B$

Answer (score 0):

Think of that $\displaystyle \bigcup$ as something like a big OR operator.

The point $x$ is in the union $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (\{x\in E,  d(x, E\setminus B)\geq \frac1n\})$ if and only if $d(x, E\setminus B)\geq \frac1n$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$.

But that is the same as saying $d(x, E\setminus B)>0$ since the sequence $1/n$ goes to zero.

So the right-hand-side is equal to  $\{x\in E \ \colon  d(x, E\setminus B)>0\}$

It should be clear that $d(x, E\setminus B)= 0$ if and only iff every open ball around $x$ meets $E/B$

So $d(x, E\setminus B) > 0$ if and only if some open ball $B(x,r)$ is disjoint from $E/B$.

But that is the same as saying $B(x,r) \subset B \ -$ which is saying $x$ is interior in $B$.

Comment: we do the the two inclusions ? right , but if i take $x\in \overset{\circ}{B} $why it is in the given set ?

Comment: You don't have to do the two inclusions if you can show the two sets are the same. It would be helpful if you included what definition of the interior you are working with, since there are several equivalent versions.

Comment: we say that $x\in \overset{\circ}{B}$ iff $B$ is an ngbh of x

Comment: How we can see this without proof the two inclusions?

Answer (score 0):

HINT.- $x\in \overset{\circ}{B}\iff $ there is an open ball $B(x;\epsilon)\subset B$

Hence $d(x,E\setminus B\ge\epsilon >0$. It follows the end.

Comment: i must take x\in B and found $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\varepsilon)\subset B$ ?

Comment: No. It is true by definition; if it does not exist then $x$ is not interior.

Comment: if we don't have the expression of $\overset{\circ}{B}$ how we do to find it ?